# Fitting ARMA Models by Statistical Softwares

Tags: r, matlab

When fitting data to get coefficient estimates for ARMA models how are the MA terms generated by the software to fit data. Every time I try to fit wouldn't i get different values as the MA(1) terms are white noise and are regenerated for every simulation?

Comment: Perhaps you will be more lucky on http://stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? When you ask about "Every time I try to fit", are you fitting the same data each time? Or are you generating new samples of white noise? Of course, new samples will yield different parameter estimates. Or are you asking why different software packages yield different parameter estimates on the same time series? If so, this may be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41446/timeseries-regression/41495#41495

Comment: Please do not cross-post. Flag your question to be migrated instead.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients for the MA(1) are a measure of the degree to which the current value of the series is influenced by (comprised of) a purely random process and the previous value of the purely random process. It is these coefficients that are estimated from the data under the assumption that the data were generated as a MA(1). The data don't change from run to run so the estimate of the MA coefficients don't change from run to run.

In other words, the **data** are assumed to come from an MA(1) with unknown coefficients $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, and the ARMA fitting software aims to estimate the population value of those coefficients.

There is nothing pseudo-random going on in the fitting of the model to the data. It is an optimisation process where by initial values values for the coefficients are derived and used to fit the model. Having done so new values for the coefficients are assigned and the fit improved. This continues till no further improvement in the fit can be achieved by changing the values of the coefficients. At that point the model has converged.

Perhaps you are confusing the theoretical definition of an MA process with the fitting of an ARMA to a stationary time series?

Comment: Nicely explained, as usual. Also, gotta love the raw text $\beta$, only destined to be properly rendered if this gets migrated to stats.stackexchange.com !

Comment: @JoshO'Brien No you misunderstand.  Gavin literally calls his parameter $\beta$.